# Preventing inputs with errors re-focusing when running parsley validate

Tags: parsley.js

This is a strange question, I know. I am working on a rather large form that uses parsley groups for validation. It's possible to be within one group, and skip to another. When a user skips, we validate the previous group. We want to run the validation, but be don't want parsley to focus on any of the fields with errors. Showing the errors is fine. So I am wondering if it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply set the `focus` option to `'none'`.